# Rspec tests fails after will_paginate-bootstrap gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, will-paginate

I installed `will_paginate-bootstrap` gem and added it to my templates

```
<%= will_paginate, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

and now my tests are failing

```
Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       /Users/user/dev/rails/my/app_rails/app/views/users/index.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
       ...end= ( will_paginate, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails )...
       ...                               ^
     # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What does this message mean? How can I fix broken tests?

Answer (score 0):

That code is using the Ruby 1.9 hash syntax. Are you still on 1.8 by chance?

Comment: nope, 1.9.3 installed via rvm (other code written in same style)

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis fixed issue `<%= will_paginate(:renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails) %>`